# Comma in "last but not least"

Tags: commas

I saw that "last but not least" are almost always written without a comma (we could write "last, but not least"). Is it an exception made especially for this sentence or is there some rule allowing us to skip a comma before "but"? Or maybe that's just a very common mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mick is correct, as a fixed phrase it doesn't need to take punctuation as a comma since you would not pause for understanding, although maybe *you might pause* rhetorically for effect. If you were to pause, the natural candidates would be: "*but*" a disjunctive, and "*but not least*" a dependent phrase.

But, if you were, indeed, to punctuate it, you could do as follows:

> Please welcome Stephanie, Mark, and -- *last, but not least,* -- Johnny.

But you could omit the dashes or substitute even more commas, but you don't want to over-comma a sentence... Readability should trump "correctness."

> Please welcome Stephanie, Mark, and *last, but not least,* Johnny.
>
> Please welcome Stephanie, Mark, and, *last[,] but not least,* Johnny. (most similar to @Mick's example)

At a minimum, we know that one **would not use** :

> **X** *...and last but, not least...*
>
> **X** *...and last but not, least...*

Answer (score 1):

It's a fixed phrase, and is normally only used in spoken English (i.e. speeches), and with no pause between *last* and *but*, so no comma is needed in reported speech.

> **last but not least**
>
> importantly, despite being mentioned after everyone else:
>
> *I would like to thank my publisher, my editor, and, last but not least, my husband.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/last-but-not-least)